# Filter rows that share two particular values

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have a table similar to what's below:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | B |

I want to return a single row when an ID has both A and B values in the VALUE column. The result I want would look like this:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A & B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | B |

How Do I combine those two rows into a single row?

This is the code I currently have

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CASE WHEN VALUE IN(A) AND VALUE IN(B) THEN ID
ELSE 1 END;
```

However, it returns a blank table.

Comment: Check the https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT ID, 'A & B' as Value
FROM mytable
group by ID
HAVING COUNT(case when VALUE = 'A' then 1 end) + COUNT(case when VALUE = 'B' then 1 end)  = 2
UNION ALL
select t.*
from mytable t
left join (
  SELECT ID
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(case when VALUE = 'A' then 1 end) + COUNT(case when VALUE = 'B' then 1 end)  = 2
) as s on s.ID = t.ID and ( t.VALUE = 'A' or t.VALUE = 'B' )
where s.ID is null
order by ID
```

Result :

```
ID  Value
1   A
2   A & B
2   C
3   B
```

First select to select only IDs having both values 'A' and 'B', while second select to get all records exepts the ones already selected by the first select

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ulD953mK)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple problem; you want to group rows by id and value, but grouping A and B values together:

```
select id, group_concat(distinct value order by value separator ' & ')
from mytable
group by id, case when value not in ('A','B') then value end
```

Or:

```
group by id, case value when 'B' then 'A' else value end
```

Anything that differentiates between non-A or B values but not between A and B will work.

This will eliminate duplicates; if you have duplicate id and value for some rows, you need to specify how you want those handled (in the case where they have value A or B as well as in the case where they don't).